# Using Platform Module within React Native causes Invariant Violation

Tags: react-native, expo

I was trying to add an external scss stylesheet to a react native which I managed to do. I then realised there were differences between ios and android in how the end result looked. So, because I was using scss, I needed to use styles.ios.js and styles.android.js to load the correct stylessheet and let react native determine which to use. All Good :-)

My issues started when I tried to use the Platform Module to reduce the two .js files down to one. So instead of react native determining based on ios.js or android.js, I would use Platform.OS within an if statement like in the example from the expo website: https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/platform-differences/

Hi All,

I was trying to add an external scss stylesheet to a react native which I managed to do. I then realised there were differences between ios and android in how the end result looked. So, because I was using scss, I needed to use styles.ios.js and styles.android.js to load the correct stylessheet and let react native determine which to use. All Good :-)

My issues started when I tried to use the Platform Module to reduce the two .js files down to one. So instead of react native determining based on ios.js or android.js, I would use Platform.OS within an if statement like in the example from the expo website: https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/platform-differences/

Like so

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";

import androidStyles from "./HomeScreen.android.scss";
import iosStyles from "./HomeScreen.ios.scss";

// console.log(Platform.OS);

let osStyles;

// prettier-ignore
if (Platform.OS = "ios") {
    osStyles = iosStyles;
  } else {
    osStyles = androidStyles;
  }

export default osStyles;
```

However, I get the following:

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "LogBox" has not been registered. This can happen if:
- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Any assistance in resolving the issue or steering me in the proper way of how I should be doing this is greatly appreciated.